# Is there a way to deploy a coffeescript app on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, coffeescript, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been playing with Node.js on Elastic Beanstalk, however I've stumbled into a block with deploying my coffeescript based app.

I noticed the `NodeCommand` parameter which ,the console says, will try `app.js` then `server.js` and then `npm start` after which I modified my `package.json` to have this section

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "coffee app.coffee"
}
```

Failing this I also configured `NodeCommand` to be `coffee app.coffee` to no avail.

Is there a way to run a coffeescript app on Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm start` should be able to work just fine. Most likely your PATH does not include the `node_modules/.bin` folder when starting inside elastic beanstalk, so try `./node_modules/.bin/coffee app.coffee` as your start script.

Answer (score 0):

I changed coffee script from being a dev dependency to a standard dependency in package.json and that solved this error for me.